# Hive : Invalid position alias in Group By Position alias: 2 does not exist

Tags: sql, hive

I have some issue with my query, and I got stuck with this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10220]: Invalid position alias in Group By Position alias: 2 does not exist error The Select List is indexed from 1 to 1

What I want to achieve is date | region | l1_name| rev

I running this query on putty server and this is the query

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(substr(trx_date, 1, 4), substr(trx_date, 6, 2), substr(trx_date, 9, 2)) AS trx_date,
  a.region,
  a.l1,
  SUM(REV) AS TOTAL_REV
FROM (SELECT
  a.trx_date,
  a.region_sales AS region,
  a.l1_name AS l1,
  SUM(a.REV) AS REV
FROM SMY.USAGE_OCS_CHG_HH a
WHERE a.event_date = '2021-12-19'
AND UPPER(l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
AND pre_post_flag = '1'
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3
UNION ALL
SELECT
  c.trx_date,
  c.region_sales AS region,
  c.l1_name AS l1,
  SUM(c.REV) AS REV
FROM SMY.USAGE_OCS_RCG_hh c
WHERE c.event_date = '2021-12-19'
AND UPPER(l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3
UNION ALL
SELECT
  b.trx_date,
  b.region_sales AS region,
  b.l1_name AS l1,
  SUM(rev) AS REV
FROM base.ocs_chg_reject b
WHERE CAST(b.event_date AS date) IN (SELECT
  CAST(MAX(b1.event_date) AS date)
FROM base.ocs_chg_reject b1)
AND b.trx_date = '2021-12-19'
AND UPPER(l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
AND pre_post_flag = '1'
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3
UNION ALL
SELECT
  e.trx_date,
  e.region_sales AS region,
  e.l1_name AS l1,
  SUM(e.Recharge_Amount) AS REV
FROM base.tc_rcg_reject e
WHERE 1 = 1
AND CAST(e.event_date AS date) IN (SELECT
  CAST(MAX(e1.event_date) AS date)
FROM base.tc_rcg_reject e1)
AND e.trx_date = '2021-12-19'
AND e.L4_NAME <> 'NQ'
AND UPPER(l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3
UNION ALL
SELECT
  trx_date,
  bnum_region_sales AS region,
  l1_name AS l1,
  CAST(SUM(price) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS REV
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM BASE.MKIOS_EVCREC_EVCVAS_NGRS
WHERE event_date = '2021-12-19'
GROUP BY 1,
         2) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  UPPER(servicecode) AS servicecode
FROM dim.ngrs_servicecode_dim b
WHERE UPPER(servicetype) = 'VAS'
AND b.event_Date IN (SELECT
  MAX(b1.event_Date)
FROM dim.ngrs_servicecode_dim b1)
GROUP BY 1) b
  ON UPPER(a.processing_code) = UPPER(b.servicecode)
WHERE UPPER(a.transaction_status) = 'COMPLETED'
AND UPPER(a.l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  trx_date,
  CAST(SUM(price) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS REV
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM BASE.MKIOS_EVCREC_EVCVAS_NGRS_REJECT a
WHERE CAST(a.event_date AS date) IN (SELECT
  CAST(MAX(b1.event_date) AS date)
FROM base.MKIOS_EVCREC_EVCVAS_NGRS_REJECT b1)
AND trx_date = '2021-12-19') a
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  UPPER(servicecode) AS servicecode
FROM dim.ngrs_servicecode_dim b
WHERE UPPER(servicetype) = 'VAS'
AND b.event_Date IN (SELECT
  MAX(b1.event_Date)
FROM dim.ngrs_servicecode_dim b1)
GROUP BY 1) b
  ON UPPER(a.processing_code) = UPPER(b.servicecode)
WHERE UPPER(a.transaction_status) = 'COMPLETED'
AND UPPER(l2_name) = 'VOICE PACKAGE'
GROUP BY 1) A
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3
```

I really appreciate if you want to help this, thank you

Comment: You could narrow this down by running each of the individual selects (ie without union) to find the code segment at fault and thereby simplify the question..

Comment: Separate your code with converting subqueries to CTEs.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it, I'm really curious why Position alias: 2 does not exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: You've tagged two different database platforms, neither of which is *Hive*

Comment: `SELECT
  *
FROM BASE.MKIOS_EVCREC_EVCVAS_NGRS
WHERE event_date = '2021-12-19'
GROUP BY 1,
         2) a` -- this section looks incorrect.

Comment: @KoushikRoy could you pls make a suggestion on what is correct ?

Comment: referring to my comment, you have a group by but you are doing `select *`. just select only required 2 columns.

Comment: @KoushikRoy yeah i get it the `select *` , but i made some change and still error SELECT
  `trx_date,
  bnum_region_sales AS region,
  l1_name AS l1,
  CAST(SUM(price) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS REV
FROM BASE.MKIOS_EVCREC_EVCVAS_NGRS
WHERE event_date = '2021-12-19'
GROUP BY 1,
         2) a`

Comment: you need to either use ` group by 1,2,3` or keep only 2 columns after select like `SELECT trx_date,   bnum_region_sales AS region, CAST(SUM(price) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS REV... `